# 別に meaning as opposed to directly saying "no"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

What's the difference between saying 別に and directly saying no.
For example:

> A: 行きたいの？
> B: 別に　（as opposed to saying 行きたくない）

I think they both mean "no, I don't want to go". But please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

「行きたくない」would sound very direct, stilted, if not rude in this context.

Saying「別に」is a little like saying "nothing in particular", "not particularly", "nothing much" in English. As a phrase it has a lot of functions and is often used to equivocate what one says.

If the response is just a brusque「別に」, it means 「別に行きたくない」(I don't want to go in particular.). But 「別に」can also be used in such expressions as

「別にどっちでもいい」: Either way. I don't care.

「別にいいよ」=「別に（そんなことをしなくても）いい」: OK

Comment: "I don't want to go in particular" sounds to me like given a choice, I wouldn't want to go but if I have to, I will. Is this the case for 別に？

Comment: @Newbie Context is king. The context you gave was a made up context right? The context is limited, but if we assume that's all there is, 「別に」would be to decline the suggestion. A direct "no" is seldom found in Japanese communication. People try to be tactful, delicate, and diplomatic about rejecting a request or declining an offer. You hardly hear people say 「いいえ」, ever. So that is a Japanese no in an informal situation. Of course following context can change it. For example: Mom to a 9-year-old「公園、行きたいの？」kid:「別に」Dad:「いいから、さっさと行け！」kid:「はい…」

Comment: Also, saying 別に could also indicate a little bit [ツンデレ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsundere). Like saying 
no when they want to say yes.